# Xcode: How do I remove an action from a object?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibutton, target-action

I need to remove an action from a object and then add a new one.

I've used this code to add the new action:

```
[Button addTarget:self action:@selector(newAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

I've then tried to use this code to remove the old action:

```
[Button removeTarget:self action:@selector(oldAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

The problem is that it somehow also removes the newAction.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In that case, a simple solution is to instead remove the old action first before adding the new one. i.e. do it the other way around.

You can remove all actions by passing `nil` for target too.

Comment: Tank you so much :)... don't know why i didn't think of that... and thanks for the nil tip, that sure made my future coding much simpler :)

Comment: passing nil to the target will not result in remove all actions: parameter: target
The target object—that is, the object to which the action message is sent. If this is nil, the responder chain **is searched for an object willing to respond to the action message**.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the action from a UIButton for example like this:

```
[self.myButton removeTarget:nil action:NULL forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllEvents];
```